# `popState` doesn't work when forwarding page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing some AJAX page reloading and everything works great, expect that `popState` only works backwards. I can go back in history, but I cannot go back forward. The question is, should `popState` work in both directions and if not, what's the opposite method to watch for moving forward?

To be exact, I've got both on-click `pushState` to work and `popState` to return me back. What doesn't work is going forward after returning back.

Example: I click on my links 3 times and go through `A-B-C` states. Now, I click back and end up at `B`. Lastly, I want to click "forward" in the browser (and not on my app) and thus end up at `C`. Well, the browser state changes, but I don't end up with `C`. Does it mean that I have to write `pushState` for browser-based behavior too? I was under impression that `popState` should handle both back and forward behaviors?

Comment: What about looking at this previous topic on stack overflow, [popstate][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760387/html-5-ajax-popstate-and-pushstate

Comment: Because it doesn't actually answer my question. I got both on-click pushState to work and popState to return me back. What doesn't work is going forward after returning back. Example: I click on my links 3 times and go through "A-B-C" states. Now, I click back and end up at B. Lastly, I want to click "forward" in the browser (and not on my app) and thus end up at C. Well, the browser state changes but I don't end up with "C"

Comment: Alright, so after playing with this for a while, the easiest solution is the one 'happy coder' was trying to (sarcastically) imply via referencing the post above. In other words - in the popstate method, you have to once again do an ajax call and reload the page data. Doing that works, but doesn't quite answer my original question. I still want to know if there's an opposite method to popstate that does the future-reload on its own.