# Bootstrap tabs - change tab when "back" button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, html5-history

I'm implementing with bootstrap3 tabs that are similar to the google+ tabs:

https://plus.google.com/109537483127696013335

Similarly to google+, I also change the URL using **history.pushState()** every time the user click a new tab.

The problem:

Let's say you viewed these 3 tabs:

```
https://plus.google.com/109537483127696013335/posts
https://plus.google.com/109537483127696013335/about
https://plus.google.com/109537483127696013335/photos
```

you have 3 items in your browser's history, if you click the back button  you'll go back to **/about** and then **/posts** but the content of the page will stay the same (**/photos**) instead of changing back to the correct tab.

This problem exists in google+, I want a better behaviour of the back button for a better UX, how can I fix it?

Comment: Please add more info

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038726/how-to-trigger-change-when-using-the-back-button-with-history-pushstate-and-pops

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                /*For browser back button press*/
                if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
                    $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
                        var url      = window.location.href;     
                        var origin   = window.location.origin;
                        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
                        var url = window.location.href;
                        var avoid = origin+pathname;
                        var abc=url.replace(avoid, '');
                        $('[href="' + abc + '"]').click();
                    }); 
                }
                /*End for browser back button press*/
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).