# Set page history with page content by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've used `pace.js` but the problem with `pace` was, the loading animation was shown after the page was completely loaded.

So, i have tried and made a solution, onclick every link on the page, jquery grabs and stops the event from the browser going direct to the link, and sends a ajax get request to that link. While the page is loading, it shows an animation on the current page. After the page is completely loaded, it replaces the whole current document with the received data and replacing the page url in the address bar.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('a').click(function() {
            var dt;
            if (/#/.test(this.href)) {
                return true;
            }else{
                document.getElementById("before-loader").style.display= "block";//show loading animation
            var that = this;
            $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: that.href,
                  success: function(response){
                    document.open();
                    document.write(response);
                    document.title = response.pageTitle;
                    window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", that.href);
                document.close();
                  },
                  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                    document.getElementById("before-loader").style.display= "none";//hide loading animation
                  }
                });
            return false;
          }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

The problem is on clicking browser back button, the url in the address bar is changing but the page content still remains the same.
How can i overcome this problem?

**Update**

`se0kjun`'s answer didn't solved my problem(i was expecting it to work after copy/paste the code provided) but put me in the right direction. After some study and rewriting the flow, it works, but i am still confused why it works.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('a').click(function() {
        if (/#/.test(this.href)) {
            return true;
        }else{
      window.history.pushState(null, 'Production Workflow & Sales Management', this.href);
            loadContent(this.href);
        return false;
      }
  });
});


function loadContent(href) {
  document.getElementById("before-loader").style.display= "block";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: href,
    success: function(response){
      document.open();
      document.title = response.pageTitle;
      document.write(response);
      document.close();
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
      document.getElementById("before-loader").style.display= "none";
    }
  });
}


window.onpopstate =  function(event) {
  link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\/]/, ""); // get filename only
  loadContent(link);
};
```

Maybe i should study more.

Comment: I think...  you need `popstate`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038726/how-to-trigger-change-when-using-the-back-button-with-history-pushstate-and-pops

Comment: but how to use `pushstate` and `popstate` with this function? i have tried, it gives me same result. the page content remains the same. can you give me example? Where the pages are stored in `pushstate` and `popstate`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to `popstate` event.

When you click a link, ajax request to `that.href`. After that, if request is successful, you would get response and call `pushstate`.

When you click a back button, `popstate` event is triggered. you can load previous page in `popstate` event handler.

Following to usage example of `popstate`

```
window.onpopstate =  function(event) {
  //you add a path in pushstate
  $('.container').load(event.state.path);
  alert('popstate');
};
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SeokjunHong/d7LL9bcb/1/)