# Bootstrap tabs are greyed out when using browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my project I'm implemented solution for Bootstrap tabs to work with browser back button. I've do that using window `popstate` event. Everything works perfectly, but the tab you back out of stays grayed/selected. This is a CSS issue? or maybe this is handled by browser?

[image]

Comment: can you please post the relevant code here?

Comment: My guess it that the state `:active` (or the class `.active`) is still on it. Try to remove it on `popstate` (See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8038811/863110) answer);

Comment: @MoshFeu: I've checked that. When I click previous button the class :active is removed.

Comment: So can you check what css gives the tab the background? It must be in the css..